# Is there any other way to test silver light application in Selenium Webdriver besides adding the Scriptable type in the source code itself?

Tags: java, silverlight, selenium

I have searched in internet but have found that the communication between Silverlight application and Selenium can be done through Javascript with the help of scriptable type. But is there any other way to achieve this using Selenium Webdriver?? Or is there any way we can know the exposed functions names that may be used for testing?

Any help would be much appreciated.. :)

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Till now i have tried to silverlight-selenium extension to Selenium RC from https://code.google.com/p/silverlight-selenium/ but i am unable to do any communication or test the example code given there. I have very few knowledge about silverlight and I need to know a way to communicate silverlight application.